# What are the branches called [1] in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

I have noticed GitLab automatically creates branches called `[1]` in the network view.

[image: sample network view]

What causes their creation, and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: What version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: @Gino: GitLab Community Edition 8.15.0. There is a red `update asap` flag next to it. This is running on a campus server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are not branches.

Those indicate that the commit hash at **[1]** was included/mentioned in one of the following:

1. A commit message in some *other* commit
2. A GitLab issue

Example:

1. Commit to branch A.
   It gets the hash `a704724f...` (you don't need the full hash)
2. Commit to a different branch B.
   Use this for the commit message: "*copy changes from a704724f*"
3. Check the Network view.
   Branch A will have a **[1]** at commit `a704724f`.

This is part of Gitlab's "it's all connected" design.

Related References:

- **References in Commits and Code review**
  https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/08/gitlab-tutorial-its-all-connected/

  > Similar to references on merge requests, you can add references in commit messages.
- **ability to reference a commit**
  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/13345

  > Simply write the commit sha and it will be linked automatically!

Comment: Thank you, this answers it. There are comments in issues referring to those commits.